# CollisionBehaviour do not working with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollisionbehavior

I am trying to implement collisions between two views.

`firstView` is view with textfields. If some textfield became firstRecognizer and keyboard frame overlap `firstView`. It moves up and if `firstView` collides with `secondView`, it should push it up too. But this does not happen. Instead `firstView` moves up until collides with `secondView` and then puts back on old place.

Here code, which I use:

```
- (void) keyboardChangeValueWithFrame:(CGRect)keyboardFrame isOpening:(BOOL)isOpening isClosing:(BOOL)isClosing {
    CGFloat animTime = .3f;
    if (isOpening && !isClosing) {
        CGRect authFillerViewFrame = self.regFillerView.frame;
        CGFloat rectDif = keyboardFrame.origin.y - authFillerViewFrame.origin.y - authFillerViewFrame.size.height;
        if ([_animator.behaviors containsObject:_collision]) {
            [_animator removeBehavior:_collision];
        }
        if (rectDif < 0) {
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            self.regFillerViewHorizCenterConst.constant = rectDif;
            [self.logoView layoutIfNeeded];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:animTime animations:^{
                _collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.regFillerView, self.logoView]];
                _collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = NO;
                _collision.collisionDelegate = self;
                _collision.collisionMode = UICollisionBehaviorModeItems;
                [_animator addBehavior:_collision];
                _collision.action = ^{

                };
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished) {
                    //
                }
            }];
        }
    } else if (!isOpening && isClosing) {
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        self.regFillerViewHorizCenterConst.constant = 0.f;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:animTime animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //
        }];
    }
}
```

Could somebody tell my mistake?
Or, may be somebody know better solution?

Comment: Looks like you could put these views in a scroll view, then when keyboard show adjust the scroll view bottom distance from super view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. My mistake was to add collision behaviour to animator before calling `layoutIfNeeded`.
Now I call `layoutIfNeeded` before adding collision behaviour and it works well.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animTime animations:^{
                _collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.regFillerView, self.logoView]];
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                _collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = NO;
                _collision.collisionDelegate = self;
                _collision.collisionMode = UICollisionBehaviorModeItems;
                [_animator addBehavior:_collision];
                _collision.action = ^{

                };
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished) {
                    //
                }
            }];
```